# Discord.js Create Channel When Member Joins

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Self explanatory.

Whenever a member joins the server, I need the bot to create a channel called `"username#0000"` **(Where username is their username and 0000 is their tag).**

Using Discord.js

I did search for an answer and I tried coding it, but the code did nothing. Literally nothing, no channel creation, no error

Comment: I did search for an answer and I tried coding it, but the code did nothing. Literally nothing, no channel creation, no error.

Comment: Then please update your question with your attempt(s). This way we can help you understand the problem and try to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure your bot has `guildMember` Intents from discord developer portal => your app.

your app needs those intents to track `guildMemberAdd` event

```
<client>.on('guildMemberAdd', member => { // replace <client> with your variable
 member.guild.channels.create(`${member.user.tag}`);
 console.log(`created a channel with ${member.user.tag} as name`);
}
```

[image]